# Generate ID based on string in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

So, I have data consists of names of the persons and I want to assign a unique numeric ID to each of them based on their first names. But the thing is I want to give same unique numeric ID to same first name person. For example, if say, there are two person with same name e.g. John, they will have same unique numeric ID value. Note that I want to assign this ID dynamically because the people data will get added constantly so every time the new people data added I need to check whether the I already have a ID for that person or do I have to generate a new one. I want do this excel with some formula or macros.

Also if anyone knows how to do this python like generating an same unique numeric ID for same string. I also try to find answer using UUID module of python, but didn't find any proper solution.

```
ID  Name
1   John
2   Michelle
1   John
3   Hasan
2   Michelle
```

As you can see I John value has same numeric ID which is '1' so as 'Michelle'

Comment: How about `John` as the ID?

Comment: I want to have numeric unique ID

Comment: It might be a  good idea to include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This UDF is a bit shaky but will work depending on how many names you have and the spread of the names ...

```
Public Function GenerateId(ByVal strText As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        strChar = UCase(Mid(strText, i, 1))
        GenerateId = GenerateId + Asc(strChar)
    Next
End Function
```

... there is a chance it will double up but it's not easy to predict.  You'd have to run all names through and check all outcomes.

Also, I know it's not a sequential ID approach starting from 1 but you didn't specify that so I used some creative licence.  :-)

Also, this will ensure that the name retains it's ID if the data is sorted differently, not sure if that's a requirement or not but it's a consideration.

Worth a potential shot anyway.